# ReactiveMongo with generics: "ambiguous implicit values"

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I'm not really sure where this error is coming from. I'm trying to migrate from an old `.find()` method where I could pass `Pattern: query: BSONDocument` to find and call `.one[T]` on it. This worked perfectly fine, but I'd like to follow the recommendations.

However, I have a feeling that my desire to create a generic database access object is causing some of this headache... take a look below.

The object that i'm trying to read from:

```
package Models

import reactivemongo.api.bson.{BSONDocumentHandler, Macros}

case class Person(name: String)

object Person {
  implicit val handler: BSONDocumentHandler[Person] = Macros.handler[Person]
}
```

The class containing the method I'm trying to execute (ignore the `Await`, etc.)

```
package Data

import reactivemongo.api.AsyncDriver
import reactivemongo.api.bson._
import reactivemongo.api.bson.collection.BSONCollection
import reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteResult

import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object DataService extends DataService

trait DataService {
  implicit val ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
  private val driver = new AsyncDriver
  private val connection = Await.result(driver.connect(List("localhost:32768")), 10.seconds)
  private val database = Await.result(connection.database("database"), 10.seconds)

  private def getCollection[T]()(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): BSONCollection = database.collection(tag.runtimeClass.getSimpleName)

  def Get[T]()(implicit handler: BSONDocumentHandler[T], tag: ClassTag[T]): Future[Option[T]] = {
    val collection = getCollection[T]
    collection.find(BSONDocument("name" -> "hello"), Option.empty).one[T]
  }
}
```

How I'm trying to get it (ignore the `Await`, this is just for test purposes):

```
val personName = Await.result(dataService.Get[Person](), 10.seconds).map(_.name).getOrElse("Not found")
```

The error that I'm getting:

```
Error:(32, 19) ambiguous implicit values:
 both object BSONDocumentIdentity in trait BSONIdentityHandlers of type reactivemongo.api.bson.package.BSONDocumentIdentity.type
 and value handler of type reactivemongo.api.bson.BSONDocumentHandler[T]
 match expected type collection.pack.Writer[J]
   collection.find(BSONDocument("name" -> "hello"), Option.empty).cursor[T]
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add type to your option in your second argument find method, for example:

```
def Get[T]()(implicit handler: BSONDocumentHandler[T], tag: ClassTag[T]): Future[Option[T]] = {
  val collection = getCollection[T]
  collection.find(BSONDocument("name" -> "hello"), Option.empty[BSONDocument]).one[T]
}
```

Comment: That did it! Can you explain why it worked, I'm curious?

Comment: This happens because `Option.empty` without type tag try to choose some type from context and found two ambiguous implicit values as candidates for option type, compiler can't choose and you need to say him explicitly which type of option should be there

Comment: as far as I remember this has already be discussed on the mailinglist (and will be improved by the api cleanup in 1.0)